# Как отправить POST-запрос от Node.js к PHP?

Tags: node.js

Есть сервер на PHP, который должен получать POST-запросы и читать передаваемые данные из переменной `$_POST['data']`; Отправляю запрос к PHP-серверу от Node.js:

```
request.post({
    url: `${domainAddr}api/image_creator/get_id`,
    body: JSON.stringify(object),
    followAllRedirects: true
},
function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Но на PHP-сервере переменная `$_POST['data]` не проходит проверку на `isset()`. Пытался найти ответ на русскоязычном и англоязычном StackOverflow, но нашёл ответы только на вопросы, касающиеся отправки данных от PHP к Node.js. Я неправильно передаю данные в Node?

Comment: а `object` содержит поле `data`?

Answer (score 0):

> $_POST - Ассоциативный массив данных, переданных скрипту через HTTP
>   методом POST при использовании **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** или
>   **multipart/form-data** в заголовке Content-Type запроса HTTP.

Если вы хотите получить данные в `$_POST['data']` то передавать надо следующим образом

```
request.post({
    url: `${domainAddr}api/image_creator/get_id`,
    form: {
        data: object // Если объект представляет собой пары ключ: значение
    },
    followAllRedirects: true
},
function(err, response, body) {
    console.log(body);
});
```

Comment: С этим кодом PHP выдаёт `Undefined index: data`

Comment: а что выдает `print_r($_POST)` ?

Comment: Показывает пустой массив `Array()`

Comment: а если попробовать вместо `form: {...}` поставить `formData: {...}` ? Я првильно предположил, что для отправки используется https://github.com/request/request ?

Comment: Да, я использую именно этот модуль. Поставил `formData: {}` и `$_POST` всё равно пуст.